# Omit unrequired JOIN with JPA Criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have three related entities Author, Category and Book in my Sping Boot application:

```
@Entity
class Category {
    @Id
    Long id;
    // other members, getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Author {
    @Id
    Long id;
    // other members, getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Book {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", nullable = false)
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The user can search for books by author and/or categories. To do so, my application offers a search REST endpoint receiving the following SearchDto:

```
class SearchDTO {
    public List<Long> authorIds;
    public List<Long> categoryIds;
}
```

I'm using the criteria API to write the DB query.

```
class BookRepositoryCustomImpl implements BookRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public search(SearchDto searchDto) {
        var cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        var query = cb.createQuery(Book.class);
        var result = query.from(Book.class);
        var predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (searchDto.authorIds != null) {
            // Version 1
            // predicates.add(book.get(Book_.author).in(searchDto.authorIds));

            // Version 2
            // var authorJoin = book.join(Book_.author);
            // predicates.add(authorJoin.get(Author_.id).in(searchDto.authorIds));
        }

        // Similar code for category constraint.

        query.select(result);
        query.where(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Both of my versions work but have their disadvantages.
Version 1 omits the unnecessary join to Author and uses the book's column author_id directly. However, as the ids are numeric values, the SQL statement contains literals but I would like to have bind variables.
When setting the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=BIND`, I get a runtime exception because a Long variable was provided but an Author object was expected. This error does not occur when using literals in the SQL statement.

With version 2, I can use bind variables but the SQL statement contains the unnecessary join to the Author table (`INNER JOIN author ON book.author_id = author.id WHERE author.id IN ($1)`).

I can also think of a version 3 where I would use `authorRepository.getOne(authorId)` to get a proxy to the author object and use a `List<Author>`. The disadvantage of this approach is all the glue code I have to write to convert the ids into entity objects.

Is there a proper way to omit the JOIN but being able to use bind variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an id into a reference to an `Author` with `getReference()`:

```
Author reference = entityManager.getReference(Author.class, authorId);
```

I'm not sure what's the type of `searchDTO.authorIds`, but assuming is a collection:

```
List<Author> authors = searchDTO.autorhIds.stream()
         .map( id -> entityManager.getReference(Author.class, id) )
         .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Now you have a list of authors that you can use as parameters for option 1.
This is going to create lazy references to the authors in the db without actually
querying the db.

**UPDATE**: I've just realized that `geOne()` and `getReference()` are the same thing, so you could also write:

```
List<Author> authors = searchDTO.autorhIds.stream()
         .map( authorRepository::getOne )
         .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: Thx! Is there a (logical) difference between `entityManager.getReference()` and my mentioned option 3 using Spring Data's `repository.getOne()`? With your approach, the required glue code is reduced a bit. Once I need an autowired repository for each type and once I need to know the entity's class type only.

Comment: I didn't know it before. but they are exactly the same thing. `getOne()` uses `getReference` underneath: https://www.netsurfingzone.com/jpa/spring-data-jpa-jparepository-getone/

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't know any cleaner way to do the same thing